# Using field api to get key of select list option

Tags: entities

I need the safe output of a key from a select list field within a field collection item.

I'm theming a field collection item and one of the fields is a select list like:

```
icon-map|Map
icon-info|Info
icon-pencil|Pencil
```

I'm using the following to create some easy to use variables;

```
$fields = array_keys($content);
foreach ($fields as $field) {
  $field_items = field_get_items('field_collection_item', $content[$field]['#object'], $field);
  $$field = render(field_view_value('field_collection_item', $content[$field]['#object'], $field, $field_items[0]));
}
```

This works fine for all fields except for the select list.  I need the `key` of that select list.  For this select list field, `$field_items` is an array which looks like:

```
array(1) { [0]=> &array(1) { ["value"]=> string(13) "icon-map" } }
```

However, `$field_icon` (result of `$$field = render(..)` ) is `Map`, which makes sense.

I can get the key by using `$field_items[0]['value']` but I'm not sure that's the best way.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this may help

```
 $key = $form_state['values']['whatever'];
$options = list_allowed_values("field_whatever");
$value = $options[$key];
```

Comment: This is right, but it's possible for it not to work (if the allowed values have been altered in the form, `list_allowed_values` won't bring back the same as what was presented to the user, for example). In that case you could also check `$form['whatever']['#options']`, assuming you're in a validate/submit handler

Comment: else use this method ,
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_list');
$key = $items[0]['value'];

If you need to match those up again at any point you can get the full key/value list from the field metadata:

$info = field_info_field('field_list');
$values = $info['settings']['allowed_values'];
$label = $values[$key];

Comment: Same problem with that method @user3783391 - you get the settings for the field, not necessarily what was actually used in the form

Comment: then in that case I suppose wat @Chris Rockwell has given  $field_items[0]['value']  is the right choice to get the key.